# How to open command prompt from powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell.
Can any body please explain me how to open command prompt from powershell.

I want to open `command prompt` and run `Dir` command

Is it possible to use `new-object -comobject` for this???

Comment: why not `cmd.exe /c dir` in a powershell prompt?

Comment: I am writing powershell script and it is executed by another program

Comment: I think it can works as well in a script.

Comment: Why run `cmd /c whatever` in the first place? I smell an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and explain the actual problem you're trying to solve by running CMD from PowerShell.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Thanks for the X-Y link-great description!

Comment: Why do you need to run `cmd.exe` at all? Just do what you need to do in PowerShell.

Answer (score 17):

Just run `start cmd`.
That will open Command Prompt in a new window.

Comment: You can also just run cmd dir. It will run just one cmd command and stay in Powershell. Same for linux on windows, use wsl <command>. No need to switch between terminals.

Answer (score 4):

`dir` is built into PowerShell. It's an alias for [`Get-ChildItem`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx). Open a PowerShell prompt from the Start Menu (All Programs --> Accessories if you're on XP, just search on higher versions of Windows), and just type `dir` and press Enter. It works similarly to the `dir` Command Prompt command.

A COM object is definitely overkill. If you really, really need to use the Command Prompt within PowerShell, just run `cmd`. That will launch an instance of the Command Prompt in the current window.

Comment: I just put an one command I need to run. There are more to executed from CMD

Comment: I think I agree with Ansgar. Could you tell us what you're trying to do at a higher level?